# Standard references in (holographic) entanglement entropy literature (Part 1)

Tags: entropy, resource-recommendations, quantum-entanglement, holographic-principle

While writing a paper, I am wondering as to what are the standard references that one refers to for these various facts about entanglement entropy. I want to know as to what are the papers one should cite for these facts and beliefs,

(like historically who are the people to be credited for these ideas)

1. (the basic definition)

   $\rho_A = - Tr_B [ \rho]$ and then the von-Neumann entropy corresponding to $\rho_A$ is $S_A = - Tr_A [\rho_A log \rho_A]$
2. (the idea of "universal" term)

   That when entanglement entropy is evaluated in any QFT then it has non-singular (believed to be "universal") parts which are believed to be independent of the regularization prescription and are believed contain data about a nearby CFT ("critical point").
3. (EE in $1+1$ CFT)

   For $1+1$ CFTs if the system $A$ is a system of length $x$ and $B$ is the complement of that in the full real line then one can show that  $S= \frac{c}{3}log \frac{x}{a}$ where $a$ is a short-distance cut-off and $c$ is the central charge (the universal data!) of the CFT.
4. (EE of perturbation in $1+1$ CFT)

   If in a $1+1$ CFT one perturbs away from the critical point then $S = {\cal A}\frac{c}{6}log \frac{ \xi}{a}$ where $\cal{A}$ is the number of boundary points of $A$ and $\xi$ is the correlation length. (..one is imagining the $A$ and the $B$ to be composed to intervals whose length is larger than $\xi$..)
5. (conjecture about EE in $1+(d>1)$ CFT)

   For CFTs in dimensions $1+(d>1)$ it is conjectured that the leading contribution to the entanglement entropy $S$ takes the form of what is called the "area law" as in, $S = f(a)\frac{\cal{A} }{ a^{d-1}}$ where $\cal{A}$ is the area of the boundary of the region $A$ and and $f$ is some function of the short-distance cut-off $a$.

Comment: An important question one might add to point 1 is what $S_A$ has to do with entanglement.

Comment: S_A is the entanglement entropy of the subsystem A.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but it is not obvious why this *quantifies* entanglement! Originally, this is just a measure of entropy, i.e., uncertainty or disorder.  (And if you want to reference the definition of reduced density matrices and the definition of $S_A$, you should certainly also reference what this has to do with entanglement!)

Comment: You know what is the reference to this?

Comment: This has been shown in http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9511030. (Note that this is a truly remarkable result: It shows that the entanglement in *any* pure bipartite state can be quantified by a *single* number.)

Comment: Thanks! May be you can help with the references for the rest too?

Comment: Point 2) has nothing to do particularly with entanglement but is a general point of scaling theory that, at criticality, any quantity (let's say additive) should be expressable as a sum of a regular part and a singular one which encodes information of the transition. I wouldn't know a single reference for this "folklore". One of the volumes of Domb and Lebovits would fit. This is very old stuff which in fact holds also classically so it's not related (only) to quantum mechanics.