# Standard references in (holographic) entanglement entropy literature (Part 2)

Tags: entropy, resource-recommendations, quantum-entanglement, holographic-principle

This is a continuation of this previously unanswered question, [Standard references in (holographic) entanglement entropy literature (Part 1)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/202136/)

I am wondering as to what are the standard references that one refers to in papers for these various facts about entanglement entropy. I want to know as to what are the papers one should cite for these facts and beliefs, (like historically who are the people to be credited for these ideas?)

- (Geometric interpretation of the universal part of EE)

  Using the Ryu-Takyanagi conjecture in the case of a spherical entangling surface one believes that the divergent and the universal parts of the entanglement entropy for CFT in odd $D$ spacetime dimensions is of the form, $S =  s_{D-2} \left (  \frac {R}{\epsilon} \right ) ^{D-2} + ... + s_1 \frac{R}{\epsilon} + s_0 + O(\epsilon)$ and for $D$ even, $S = s_{D-2} \left ( \frac {R}{\epsilon} \right ) ^{D-2} + ...+ s_2 \left ( \frac{r}{\epsilon} \right ) ^2 + s_L ln \left ( \frac{2R}{\epsilon} \right ) + \tilde{s_0} + O(\epsilon^2)$. The $s_0$ and the $s_L$ are the expected universal terms. $s_0$ is proportional to the partition function of the Euclidean CFT on $S^D$. $s_L$ is proportional to the central charge defined from the coefficient of the Euler density in the trace anomaly.
- (The $- \frac{\xi(3) }{8\pi^2}$ effect in $\phi ^4$ theory on $AdS_4$)

  One can think of the $(\phi^2)^2$ field theory as the free scalar field theory being deformed in the UV by a double-trace term of the form $\delta S^{UV} \sim \int d^3x J^{(0)}J^{(0)} $ where $J^{(0)} = \sum_{i=1} ^N \phi^i \phi^i$ is a scalar singlet operator of scaling dimension $\Delta = 1$ in the UV.  It is known that for a double-trace deformation like this in the UV to flow to to a  IR fixed point one needs the operator to have UV dimensions in the range $(\frac{d}{2}-1, \frac{d}{2})$ and here one sees that this will satisfy the condition for $d=3$. For such a deformation it has been shown for the free energy ($F = - log Z$) both from the bulk (a Vasiliev theory on $AdS_4$) as well as from the boundary that $\delta F =  F^{UV} -  F^{IR} = - \frac{\xi(3) }{8\pi^2} + O(\frac{1}{N}) $